# Force AWS Glue crawler to create more than one table

Tags: aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have some data in my S3 bucket, divided by some folders, each of them representing an event tracked. The schemas have some similarities, but are different.

When I run the crawler pointing to that bucket, it creates only one table. Is there a way to force it to create many tables?

In the following print I show how I've configured the crawler, but I have tested many configs.
[image]

Comment: It maybe one table, but may have multiple parition. Have you checked that?

Comment: Hey Marcin it's not that, I'm sure

Comment: You can specify each path separately in the crawler settings, but it won't help if for example you store files based on date and you want it to create a table for each of the dates separately

Comment: Yeah, I want it to scale, many other events will be created and I don't want to input them manually every time